# Is "just.....million" an absolute phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

The earnings of the company last year were US$100 million, just 1 million below our earnings forecast of US$101 million.

Is the above sentence grammatical ? "just 1 million below our earnings forecast of US$101 million" is it an absolute phrase ?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatical. But [here](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/absolutephrase.htm) it says that an absolute phrase combines a noun and a participle. There is no participle in this sentence, so why do you think it is an absolute phrase? Can you explain what you think the sentence means, how it should be parsed? I think you may be reading something in it that is not there.

Comment: Grammatical except for the fact that "earnings" takes a plural verb. Otherwise somewhat clumsy beginning. Consider: "The company's earnings last year totaled US$1M." The rest of the sentence is fine. I join oerkelens in not knowing what you mean by "absolute."

Comment: "just.....million" is definitely a phrase. It is definitely not a prepositional phrases, participle phrase, gerund or infinitive phrase. I am left with noun phrase and absolute phrase. Since noun phrase function as subjects, objects, and complements while absolute phrase is a word group that modifies an entire sentence, I took a bet on absolute phrase. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical.

The phrase "just 1 million below our earnings forecast of US$101 million" is a noun phrase, functioning as an *[appositive](https://www.google.com/search?q=appositive)*. It's not modifying the whole sentence; rather, it's merely alternative phrasing of "US$100 million". (This is the same construction as "my friend Susan", where "Susan" and "my friend" are two ways of referring to the same person.)